# Can't acces method class, from another class (and module) in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, class, oop

the title problem ! I don't know why I can't use a method from another class in NodeJS. This is my first time using classes in Node.
Let see some code:

```
'use strict'

api_client.js:

class ApiClient {

    constructor(userQuery) {
        this.userQuery = userQuery;
    }

    getResponse() {
        try {
            const response = {"my query": this.userQuery}"this is an example to simplify";
    } catch(error) {
            throw new Error(error.message);
        }
    }

}

module.exports = ApiClient;




api_service.js:

'use strict';

const apiClient = require('../clients/api_client');

class ApiService {

    static async getResponse(userQuery) {

        try {
            const instance = await new ApiClient(userQuery);
            const response = instance.getResponse(); //I think here is the problem. WebStorme tell me that I can't acces to getResponse method.
            const responseJson = response.json();
            return responseJson;
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error.message);
        }
    }
```

So I can't use the "getResponse" method from ApiClient class in ApiService. Something wrong !?

thanks!

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: I don't, just there is no response from postman. I've tried put some console.log but I couldn't get the problem, I can console.log the new ApiClient rightly too, but I can't get the method.

Comment: what happens if you remove `await` from `const instance = await new ApiClient(userQuery);` ? it doesn't seem like it should return a promise.

Comment: nothing,  is the same, the new obj prints equal form in both cases. If I put console.log(ApiClient) under "const instance" line, I get this = "ApiClient { userQuery: 'the query params' }"

Comment: I got it... the program crash in this line:

`const responseJson = response.json();`
 the .json() methos doesn't work.